# Evolution email content height

Tags: evolution

My evolution message content height is changed to few pixels, even in opened message window.

Can you help me how to set content height back to normal please?

Edit: Lubuntu 22.04 + Gnome Evolution

[image]

Comment: Can't you just *drag* the window larger... that is common for many GNOME apps (*of which the evolution MUA is one*).  You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details, but this should work for all.   *By moving the mouse pointer into the correct place, you'll note (depending on your chosen theme of course) the pointer change to one which allows you to adjust the size*

Comment: Sorry! i forgot to mention. I installed gnome evolution on lubuntu 22.04. It's not allowing to resize with mouse pointer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a compatibility problem between older versions of Evolution and recent versions (>= 2.40.0) of WebKitGTK.

If you installed both from the official repositories there should be an update available now or very soon and you don't need to do anything special.

If you installed one of them on your own from a third-party repository you can can either downgrade the libwebkit2gtk packages to the previous version that you were using, or upgrade Evolution.

More details here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/2001

Comment: Thanks! I could fix it, with your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install evolution

then close evolution and start it again and it should work (at least for me it did).